# Javascript Modification for Mouse Leaving Browser Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript that I use to display a lightbox when a visitor's mouse breaks the browser plane... here's my page:  [http://mudchallenger.com/index-test2.html][1]

However, if you move your mouse too fast, it does not recognize that you've left the page and the script does not fire.

Does anyone know how to modify this script so that it fires if the mouse is not present in the window?

Here's the script:

```
var oldPosition = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth / 2 - $('#exitpopup').width() / 2));
    $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight / 2 - $('#exitpopup').height() / 2));
     var position = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();

        if(position < 10) {
            if(oldPosition != -1) {
                if(position < oldPosition) {
                    // Show the exit popup
                    $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
                    $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
                }
                oldPosition = position;
            } else {
                oldPosition = position;
            }
        }
        $('#divData').html(oldPosition + " : " + position);
    });

    $('#exitpopup_bg').click(function() {
        $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
        $('#exitpopup').slideUp();
    });
});
```

I include this tag in the .html page

```
<?php require('exitpopup.php'); ?>
```

Here is the 'exitpopup.php' script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var oldPosition = -1;


$(document).ready(function() {


    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {


$('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth / 2 - $('#exitpopup').width() / 2));
 $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight / 2 - $('#exitpopup').height() / 2));
 var position = e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();


        if(position < 20) {
            if(oldPosition != -1) {
                if(position < oldPosition) {
                    // Show the exit popup
                    $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
                    $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
                }
                oldPosition = position;
            } else {
                oldPosition = position;
            }
        }
        $('#divData').html(oldPosition + " : " + position);


    });

    $('#exitpopup_bg').click(function() {
        $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
        $('#exitpopup').slideUp();
    });


});

</script>

<style type="text/css">

    #exitpopup
    {
        text-align:center;
    }

    #exitpopup h1
    {
        margin-top:0px;
        padding-top:0px;

    }   

    #exitpopup p
    {
        text-align:left;
    }

</style>



<div style="display: none; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; background:#000000; opacity: .9; filter:alpha(opacity=0.9); z-index:999998;" id="exitpopup_bg">




</div>
<div style="width:975px; height:575px; margin:0px auto; display:none; position:fixed; color:#000000; padding:0px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px; z-index:999999; background-image: url(exit-gate/exit-gate-bg2.png);" id="exitpopup">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your html?

Comment: Hey @ElliotM, like the whole html page?  All I did was include the php tag in the .html page, and it runs the .php script.

Comment: The HTML that contains the elements referenced above (#divData, exitpopup_bg, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, yes... I'm kinda a novice and just fumble and google until I get what I want.     I will edit the original post and include there.

Comment: @ElliotM I just added to the original post.  Thank you man

Comment: That's a pretty horrible user experience :(

Comment: @Jivings Please elaborate.

Comment: Have you ever been annoyed with marketing webpages that ask you if "you're sure you want to leave this page?". This is just slightly better than that. You are forcing a view to change without the user intending it.

Comment: @Jivings I understand that, but it is much less obtrusive and one final attempt to turn our abandoning visitors into conversions. Especially if we have an influx of free traffic from a groupon or something where we get astronomical amount of traffic within a day or two.   I do understand your point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating thing with positioning.

```
$('html').hover(
    function() {
        console.log('Entered browser window')
    },
    function() {
        console.log('Left browser window')
    }
)
```

Detects both enter/leave or use just `.mouseleave()` on 'html' to detect when mouse left. So in your case remove your entire `$(document).mousemove` handler and replace it with

```
$('html').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
   $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();
})
```

Add left/top positioning of the popup as needed, but ideally it should be in CSS only

Comment: Thank you for the quick help!!   Because I'm somewhat a novice at this, and would probably spend a considerable amount of time figuring this out,  what in that script should I replace with your suggested code? Could you put it in context for me?

Comment: @user3089680 update my answer, please let me know if it worked for u

Comment: Is there any way to customize this a bit more?  If the mouse leaves the window but is still within the browser? 

Hard to explain, but I don't want it to trigger the script if they move their mouse to the side by accident.. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, but I don't think this is possible. JavaScript controls whatever is inside browser window, but not outside.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if the mouse leaves the window at the top side? (and NOT at the bottom or both sides) in other words, so you'll know when the mouse goes to the addressbar or the close/minimize/maximize buttons. Maybe doable by adding a little div at the top that would also trigger a mousein/out.. not sure..

Comment: @Malachi you can simple pass `event` object and check `clientY` property - here's a small demo http://jsfiddle.net/u5N7F/ - you can add some code to detect moving out on sides as well